# Seleccionar 3 datos y contarlos en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

soy nuevo relativamente en el mundo de la programación y más todavia en el uso de bases de datos.

Mi problema radica en que tengo una base de datos en la que guardo direcciones IP, Fechas y  Direcciónes URL, necesito saber que entre un rango de fechas, Por ejemplo del 01/05/2022 al 15/05/2022 Me diga cuantas ips diferentes han visitado mi sitio.

Osea, os lo muestro un poco mas gráficamente.

```
-------Fecha-| -----IP------------| --------- URL -------------------------<br>
'2022-11-01' | '95.63.93.243'     |  'index.php'<br>
'2022-11-01' | '95.63.93.243'     |  'Promociones.php'<br>
'2022-11-01' | '95.63.93.243'     |  'index.asp'<br>
'2022-11-02' | '95.63.93.243'     |  'promo.asp?id_promo=27'<br>
'2022-11-02' | '95.63.93.243'     |  'index.php'<br>
'2022-11-02' | '95.63.93.243'     |  'Promociones.php'<br>
'2022-11-03' | '95.63.93.243'     |  'index.asp'<br>
'2022-11-03' | '95.63.93.243'     |  'promo.asp?id_promo=27'<br>
```

'2022-11-03' | '66.249.65.200'     |  'promo.asp?id_promo=27'
'2022-11-03' | '92.177.159.53'     |  'index.php'
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Lo que necesitaría es que me dijese, por ejemplo, para el día 01 Se ha visitado 1 sola vez, para el día 02 se ha visitado también 1 vez, el día 03 se ha visitado en cambio 3 veces (numero de ips diferentes por cada día)

Ahora mismo tengo la siguiente función que creo que se le acerca un poco.

select distinct ip, count(*) as Total, Fecha from contador2 where Fecha between '2022/05/12' and '2022/05/12' group by fecha;

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa en este punto: *lo que necesitaría seria que me dijese de esa tabla, el día 01 la ip 95.63.93.243 Visitó la url Index.php 2 veces*. En la muestra de datos eso no ocurre nunca. `index.php` fue visitada sólo una vez el día `01`, y el día `02` fue visitada otra vez. ¿Lo que necesitas no es más bien contar cuántas veces fue visitada **en el rango de fechas**, donde sí fue visitada dos veces? Si es así, explica qué fecha debe mostrarse en el `SELECT`, pues habrá varias fechas del rango y debe decidirse si mostrar la mayor o la menor por ejemplo.

Comment: @A. Cedano tienes toda la razon, he planteado mal mi pregunta. necesito ver las visitas totales de cada dia, osea contar las diferentes ips para cada dia.

Comment: Perdona mi insistencia, pero tampoco se entiende, ahora la confusión es esta: *`osea contar las diferentes ips para cada dia`*. ¿Quieres contar las veces que una URL fue visitada por día aunque las IP sean diferentes o quieres contar las veces en que una URL fue visitada por cada IP cada día? Pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema, poniendo un ejemplo de los resultados que esperas basado en la muestra de datos.

Comment: @A. Cedano ya he modificado mi pregunta, espero que ahora esté mas clara.

Comment: Se entiende mejor el enunciado, pero falta un aspecto. ¿Necesitas mostrar las IP en los resultados de la consulta? Lo digo porque en el caso de ejemplo, la URL habría sido visitada por la IP `95.63.93.243`. y por la IP `92.177.159.53` y en el conteo de ESA fila habría la posibilidad de una o de otra, ¿cuál de las dos habría que mostrar? Y es lo mismo, si hubiera 100 IP distintas, ¿cuál de las 100 IP habría que mostrar? Cuando trabajas con GROUP BY este tipo de cosas deben quedar meridianamente claras. Misma duda con respecto a la fecha, ¿cuál hay que mostrar?

Comment: Sería muy esclarecedor que pongas un ejemplo del resultado que esperas obtener. Si quieres solamente el total de visitas y la URL, sólo esas dos columnas irían en el `SELECT` porque se agrupa por ellas. Si quieres más datos, como fecha o IP, debes especificar **cuál de ellas** (¿la mayor, la menor, todas?) dado que en el grupo podría haber varias.

Comment: Sinceramente la fecha es lo que me interesa, me gustaria que me dijera algo como 01/01/2022 -> 100 Visitas
02/01/2022 -> 120
03/01/2022 -> 230....

Comment: También podría valerte esta consulta: `SELECT Fecha, URL,  COUNT(*) AS Total FROM contador2 WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '2022/05/01' AND '2022/05/15' GROUP BY Fecha,url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues, simplemente con estos cambios, ya lo tendrías:

```
select 
    DATE(Fecha),URL, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as Total 
from contador2 
Where 
    Fecha between '2022/05/01' 
    and '2022/05/15' 
group by 1,2;
```

Sobre tu intento, cuando agrupas, no hace falta el `DISTINCT` y, SIEMPRE, debes utilizar una función de totales para los campos por los que no agrupas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero he planteado mal la consulta, lo que necesito es contar las diferentes ips que visitan las diferentes urls, osea en el ejemplo que puse la ip 95.63.93.243 visitó la web el dia 01, 1 vez (en varias URL pero 1 sola visita) de ahi que pusiera yo "distinct" lo que tengo dudas es como hacer la consulta,

Comment: @neofilo Ok, ya lo tienes... Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, eso es justo lo que necesitaba.